# is using .catch with async await can cause problem?

Tags: javascript, async-await

My question is, using .catch with async await can cause problem ?

for example:

```js
function f1() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    rej(1)
  })
}

async function f2() {
  await f1().catch(ex => { }) // this is what I mean
}

f2()
```

Comment: Why would catching a problem cause a problem?  What problem are you concerned about causing?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `.catch`, but it's unclear why you would want to. You could write the same thing using try/catch: `try { await f1(); } catch (ex) {}`

Comment: no it won't cause problem

Comment: I want to use it this way to catch specific errors and take the right action for it without stopping the whole function. if I use try catch for this, the code will get polluted really quick. thx for answers

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this

```
function f1(){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    rej(1)
  })
}

async function f2(){
  try {
    const response = await f1();
    // use the response from f1()
  } catch(err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

f2()
```

something along these lines as `async/await` is a wrapper for promises that allow you to write synchronous-looking code. Otherwise you'd be looking at

```
function f2(){
  let response;
  f1().then(res => {
    response = res
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw Error(err)
  });
}
```

Comment: What purpose should the `throw new Error(err)` in both he try-catch block and the `.chatch(…)` have? And in the `f1().then(res => {` that does not return the Promise from `f1`, would result in an unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: Sure. I see what you're saying. However, this person is trying to understand the working differences between promise resolution/rejection juxtaposed with async/await. They are obviously mixing up some of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "problem", but this code:

```
async function f2() {
  await f1().catch(ex => { /* ... code in catch ... */ }) // this is what I mean
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
async function f2() {
  try {
    await f1()
  } catch (ext) {
    /* ... code in catch ... */
  } // this is what I mean
}
```

And as you said it can be useful to use `.catch` instead of `try-catch` as is can - not in every case - make your code more readable. But you need to always think about if `.catch` is the right choice for readability. It works well if you use it for recoverable error handling.